# rails 4 paperclip: missing required attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a problem with paperclip and rails 4.
When uploading an image, I get the following error:

```
Image model missing required attr_accessor for 'pic_file_name'
```

When adding the recommended attr_accessors

```
  attr_accessor :pic_file_name
  attr_accessor :pic_content_type
  attr_accessor :pic_file_size
  attr_accessor :pic_updated_at
```

the record is saved but the :pic column is empty, nothing was uploaded.

I also tried whitelisting :pic_file_name

```
 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_image
      @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:title, :pic, :pic_file_name)
    end
```

but no success.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this by creating a new column

```
 def change
    add_column :images, :pic_file_name, :string
  end
```

might be necessary for rails 4 apps, don't know.
Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing pic_file_name

```
def pic_file_name
 pic
end

def pic_file_name(file_name)
 pic = file_name
end
```

Comment: you mean into the model?